# Composer cannot install Feeds Extensible Parsers?

Tags: feeds

I'm trying to install the feeds extensible parser module using Composer but the following error keeps showing up.
Problem 1

```
- Root composer.json requires drupal/feeds_ex, it could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

Potential causes:

- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting

  see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
- It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

I tried to override minimum stability by --stability command but it doesn't work, I also tried changing minimum stability to dev as well as manually adding the module to the require section in the composer.json but nothing seems to work. Could someone help?

Comment: There is not enough information to provide an answer. Please provide the command you typed to attempt to install the module.